# Альтернатива password_verify в nodejs

Tags: node.js, password, password-hash, blowfish, bcrypt

у меня в базе есть куча паролей, хэшированных в php (password_hash) вида *$2y$**. Мне надо сделать верификацию этих хэшей в nodejs. В php это делалось с помощью password_verify.

Сразу оговорюсь: я знаю что такое bcrypt blowfish, я знаю о существовании сторонних пакетов в npm. А еще я знаю, что **npm - помойка** и ставить/обновлять оттуда ничего нельзя (как минимум без тщательного, длительного и разностороннего аудита кода).

Мне нужно решение **БЕЗ УСТАНОВКИ ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫХ ПАКЕТОВ**, исключительно силами node и встроенной библиотеки crypto. Может у кого-то есть мысли как быстро и малой кровью верифицировать пароли или имеются наработки в этой области не более чем на 15-20 строк кода, который можно было бы быстро проанализировать.

Comment: Вы усложняете себе жизнь излишней паранойей.

Comment: @andreymal Вполне возможно, но эта моя "паранойя" не раз оправдывала свое существование.